# processing - mouseOver on objects

Tags: processing, processing.js

I'm trying to figure out how to detect in processing / processing js when the mouse is over a certain object on screen. In this case, I am drawing lines. It seems like processing can't attach a "listener" to an object, so I would have to do this with some sort of coordinate detection - but I haven't found any good examples of this. This is my code so far:

```java
void draw() {
 for(int i = 0; i < commLength; i ++) { 
  ...
  line(circ.x, circ.y, circ.x + dir.x, circ.y + dir.y);
 }
}

void mouseOver(){
 //need to detect if mouse is over one of the lines.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is to check if the mouse is within a certain distance from the start and the end of the line:

```
boolean mouseIsOverLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  float d = dist(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  float d1 = dist(x1, y1, mouseX, mouseY);
  float d2 = dist(x2, y2, mouseX, mouseY);

  // distance between vertices must be similar to sum of distances from each vertex to mouse
  if (d1 + d2 < d + MOUSE_OVER_LINE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

where the line goes from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`. This image roughly shows an example that would return false (red lines) and one that would return true (green lines), depending on the value of `MOUSE_OVER_LINE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD`. The mouse coordinates are at the orange dots in each case.

[image]